# Mongo $in query with case-insensitivity

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose.js to perform an $in query, like so:

```
userModel.find({
            'twitter_username': {
                $in: friends
            }
        })
```

`friends` is just an array of strings. However, I'm having some case issues, and wondering if I can use Mongo's $regex functionality to make this $in query case-insensitive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/):

> To include a regular expression in an $in query expression, you can
>   only use JavaScript regular expression objects (i.e. /pattern/ ). For
>   example:
>
> { name: { $in: [ /^acme/i, /^ack/ ] } }

One way is to create regular Expression for each Match and form the friends array.

```
 var friends = [/^name1$/i,/^name2$/i];
 or,
 var friends = [/^(name1|name2)$/i]
 userModel.find({"twitter_username":{$in:friends }})
```

Comment: Went for this, but I made it work with one Regex in the array, ie. [/foo|bar/i]

Comment: Cool. That would be more optimum. Would definitely like to include that in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Its a little tricky to do something like that

at first you should convert `friends` to new regex array list with:

```
var insesitiveFriends = [];

friends.forEach(function(item)
{
    var re = new RegExp(item, "i");
    insesitiveFriends.push(re);    
})
```

then run the query

```
db.test.find(
{
   'twitter_username':
    {
        $in: insesitiveFriends
    }
})
```

I have the sample documents in test collection

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5485e2111bb8a63952bc933d"),
    "twitter_username" : "David"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5485e2111bb8a63952bc933e"),
    "twitter_username" : "david"
}
```

and with var `friends = ['DAvid','bob'];` I got both documents

Comment: This is the right answer for those that are using variables instead of hard strings.

Comment: Good Answer @Disposer

Comment: This isn't exactly right. This will match more than you mean. It will look for substrings of "David" including "David_more_at_the_end". `new RegExp(\`^${myVar}$\`, "i")` will limit it to any exact matches (ignoring the casing).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, mongodb tends to be pretty case-sensitive at the core. You have a couple of options:

1) Create a separate field that is a lowercase'd version of the twitter_username, and index that one instead. Your object would have twitter_username and twitter_username_lc. The non-lowerecase one you can use for display etc, but the lowercase one you index and use in your where clause etc.

This is the route I chose to go for my application.

2) Create a really ugly regex from your string of usernames in a loop prior to your find, then pass it in:

```
db.users.find({handle:{$regex: /^benhowdle89|^will shaver|^superman/i } })
```

Note that using the 'starts with' ^ carrot performs better if the field is indexed.